# Refreshing a page from another page in javascript

Tags: extjs, page-refresh

I am standing in one page. I clicked on a button and it opened a new page in another tab. After completing the process in new tab, it will be closed. The data entered in the new tab should be updated in the old tab also. So how will I refresh the old page?
Currently the new tab is just closed after the process. Now can the old page be seen? Until  refreshing the data is not updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to call this javascript from the inside of the popup window:

```
self.opener.location.reload();
```

or

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

and wrap it in an unload function like

```
window.onunload = function(){ ... };
```

should work this way ( but not tested yet ).

Comment: you might even focus the old page: window.opener.focus();